# Problem with Pandas series.replace result

Tags: python, pandas, series

**I am using pandas series.replace with regex=True but the replacement results are confusing.**

**My requirement** : Perform a case **insensitive** replacement for the values in the dictionary, only if the column value ***exactly*** matches with any of the **to_replace** list of values

```
import pandas as pd

replace_dict = {'True': 1, 'Yes': 1, 'False': 0, '.0+$': ''}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['true', 'TRue','False', 'Yes', '2.0', '2.0000', '.0002', 'A true warrior'], columns=['col_a'])

keys, values = list(replace_dict.keys()), list(replace_dict.values())
keys = ['(?i){}'.format(x) for x in keys]
df['col_b'] = df['col_a'].replace(to_replace=keys, value=values, regex=True)

df
```

**Actual Output** : See the highlighted below. why it replaces the whole value ie., **'A true warrior' with 1?**

[image]

**Expected Output** Please help me in getting the expected output

```
        col_a           col_b
0   true            1
1   TRue            1
2   False           0
3   Yes             1       
4   2.0             2       
5   2.0000          2
6   .0002           .0002
7   A true warrior  A true warrior
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression matches a substring of `A true warrior` and thus the value is replaced.

If you want to replace only if the whole word is matched, you should use a regular expression like:

```
keys = ['^(?i){}$'.format(x) for x in keys]
```

`^` and `$` match the start and the end of the string resp.

Comment: Thanks but in  'A true warrior' why it replaces the whole string. it would make sense only if the substring is replaced, in this case 'true' to be replaced with 1.

What if i want substring replacements only. Say like 'A true warrior' with 'A 1 warrior'.

Comment: also Please give me the regex to replace only the substring .. 'A 1 warrior'